# TransactionScope "Связь с диспетчером нижележащей транзакции не удалась."

Tags: c#, sql-server, исключения, транзакции

Приветствую!

Есть такой консольный "стенд":

```
class Program
{
    static string _имяСервераБД = "ServerDB";
    static string _имяБД_1 = "DB1";
    static string _имяБД_2 = "DB2";
    static string _имяБД_3 = "DB3";
    static string _имяПользБД = "sa";
    static string _парольПользБД = "12345678";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                ЯЧтотоДелаю();

                ЯДелаюЧтотоБольше();

                ТеДвоеНаСамомДелеПростоТупят();

                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }

    static void ЯЧтотоДелаю()
    {
        try
        {
            String строкаСоединения = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={2};Password={3};Connect Timeout=10", _имяСервераБД, _имяБД_1, _имяПользБД,_парольПользБД);
            String текстЗапроса = String.Format("INSERT INTO dbo.Test (Test) VALUES ('Тестим1: {0}')", DateTime.Now);
            ВыполнитьЗапросБД(строкаСоединения, текстЗапроса);
            Console.WriteLine("Я что-то сделал.");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    static void ЯДелаюЧтотоБольше()
    {
        try
        {
            String строкаСоединения = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={2};Password={3};Connect Timeout=10", _имяСервераБД, _имяБД_2, _имяПользБД, _парольПользБД);
            String текстЗапроса = String.Format("INSERT INTO dbo.Test (Test) VALUES ('Тестим2: {0}')", DateTime.Now);
            ВыполнитьЗапросБД(строкаСоединения, текстЗапроса);
            Console.WriteLine("А я сделал больше!");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    static void ТеДвоеНаСамомДелеПростоТупят()
    {
        try
        {
            String строкаСоединения = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={2};Password={3};Connect Timeout=10", _имяСервераБД, _имяБД_3, _имяПользБД, _парольПользБД);
            String текстЗапроса = String.Format("INSERT INTO dbo.Test (Test) VALUES ('Тестим3: {0}')", DateTime.Now);
            ВыполнитьЗапросБД(строкаСоединения, текстЗапроса);
            Console.WriteLine("Да ничего вы не сделали...");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static void ВыполнитьЗапросБД(String cтрокаСоединения, String текстЗапроса)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cтрокаСоединения))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(текстЗапроса, cn))
            {
                cn.Open();

                try
                {
                    cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    cn.Close();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Который используя `TransactionScope` последовательно выполняется три метода, в которых делается подключение к разным БД в рамках одного сервера и в таблицу `Test`,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] ([Test] varchar(50) NULL)
```

что-то там пишется.

В результате первый метод выполняется, а вот на втором падает с исключением:

> System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException: "Связь с
>   диспетчером нижележащей транзакции не удалась."
>
> Внутреннее исключение: 
>   COMException: Диспетчеру транзакций MSDTC не
>   удалось получить транзакцию от исходного диспетчера транзакций из-за
>   проблем со связью. Возможные причины: наличие брандмауэра, в списке
>   исключений которого отсутствует процесс MSDTC, отсутствие для двух
>   компьютеров возможности обнаружения друг друга по именам NetBIOS или
>   поддержка сетевых транзакций, отключенных для одного из двух
>   диспетчеров транзакций. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8004D02B)

Настройки для DTC на серваке и клиенте идентичные:

[image: Скрин настроек]

Сервера: WinServer 2008 R2, SQL 2008

Фаерволы везде отключены, все друг друга видят...более того я вижу со строны сервера в списке транзакцию:

[image: Скрин с транзакцией]

Но она падает в `Aborted` и я не понимаю почему...

Есть логи от DTC, но по ним яснее не становиться, что не так...

[image: Скрин логов]

Смущает в логах

> received request to abort the transaction from beginner

но кто этот `beginner`, если клиент, то с чего ему это делать...

В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо!